# Problem with interacting with external contract

Tags: solidity, remix, contract-deployment

I've created universal contract that get balance of any NFT(I parse NFT contract address).

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

interface myInterface {
    function balanceOf(address owner) external view returns (uint256);
}

contract myContact {

    function getBalance(address _myAddy, address _someContractAddy) external view returns(uint256 balance) {
        myInterface monkeyContract = myInterface(_someContractAddy);
        balance = monkeyContract.balanceOf(_myAddy);
        return balance;
    }
}
```

So this works. Now I tried to make contract that set approval or sends NFT. Idea was also to give a contract address of NFT.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

interface myInterface {
    function setApprovalForAll(address operator, bool approved) external;
}

contract myContact {
    function transfer(address _toAddy, bool _approved, address _someContractAddy) external {
        myInterface targetContract = myInterface(_someContractAddy);
        targetContract.setApprovalForAll(_toAddy, _approved);
    }
}
```

But I don't get what I expected. I'm getting my contract address to be an operator address?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
targetContract.setApprovalForAll(_toAddy, _approved)
```

this function in your case allows to `_toAddy` make `transferFrom` for tokens that ownable by your contract, not your wallet. Because this function targets for `msg.sender`, that is an address that cause `call`. (not initiator of tx).

If you wanna approve your tokens for another address (_toAddy) you must make this manually from your wallet, or transfer tokens to contract and only after that call approve.

This is not avoidable, because this is security rule. Noone cant approve to spend a token except actual token owner. And your contract is NOT token owner.

Comment: Hmm, so in order to accomplish successful transfer of NFT, I have to transfer it on my contract `myContract` and then call a function `setApprovalForAll` to `_toAddy` if I understood you right? But again i have no clue what functions I need to call to transfer NFT at first. Even simpler idea would be to do direct transfer from my wallet -> `_toAddy` using `myContract` if that's possible. If it is can you give me a clue or at least give me some directions :D

Comment: 1) You can approveForAll from you wallet to your contract
2) Inside your contract you can call transferFrom (from wallet to contract)
3) inside your contract call transferFrom (from contract to _addy).

Last step without approve from contract to _addy, because you call transferFrom from  actual owner of NFT

Comment: There is one rule. Owner of NFT can call transferFrom(ownerOfNFT => anyAddress) without approve. Any another contract or wallet can call transferFrom (anyAddress => anyAddress) only if owner of NFT gave approve for this action.